# How to get all users in Firestore except those in block array list inside user document?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app with Firebas Firestore as database. In my app users can block other users to exclude them from the next query.

Which database structure should I use to do the Firestore query?

When you block someone, the userID will be stored in an array inside your user document. The Firestore query only provides 'array-contains' operator to filter based on array values. So I need to query "array-NOT-contains" but Firestore doesn't provide it.

**DB structure**

```
users: {
   user1:{
      name: "Lorem Ipsum"
      blockedUsersId: [
         0: user1,
         1: user2]
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to query "array-NOT-contains"

There is no way you can perform a query against a Firestore collection for documents that don't have a certain value in an array. There is no "array-not-contains" operator. Why? Because the queries in Firestore work based on indexes that exist, and not based on indexes that don't exist. Imagine you have a collection of billion documents and you want to search for the non-existence of some value in an array. That means that Firestore needs to check all documents in order to provide a result. Checking such an enormous number of documents doesn't scale, hence the absence of the "array-not-contains" operator.

Comment: Is there any better solution with firestore to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: If you work with small data sets, then you can download all documents and perform the search on the client.

Comment: Hey Fortray. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?